# Select [column a] from table where there are no instances of [column b = arbitrary value]

Tags: mysql, select

I want to have a table setup to log attempts, and be able to find out if there was ever a successful attempt at a particular action. So if I were to have a table 'attempt', with the fields 'action' and 'success', I would want to select all actions for which there is no success = 1. What would be the appropriate select statement for this case?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query:

SELECT action FROM attempt
GROUPBY action
HAVING SUM(success) = 0;

This counts the total numbers of success responses for this particular action when grouped by action. When count is 0 means there was no sucess=1 found.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you think that this solves the problem?

Comment: This counts the total numbers of success responses for this particular action when grouped by action.    When count is 0 means there was no sucess=1 found.

Comment: Please add such explanation to the answer itself - if the OP asks for help in this context, he might not know why your code solves his problem, and without an explanation, he cannot learn that